# prototype $ strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

i got a null object when i try to fetch an element by id using prototype's $ function, and got this strange behaviour:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $$('.answer').each(function(answer) {
    console.log('answer.id: ' + answer.id);
    console.log('$(answer.id): ' + $(answer.id)); # works, so the element does exists
    console.log("$('answer_73'): " + $('answer_73')); # this doesn't, why?..
    console.log(' ');
  }); 
});
```

the divs are like this:

```
<div id="answer_73" class="answer"> ...
```

and there's no markup error

the logs:

....
answer.id: answer_73
$(answer.id): [object HTMLDivElement]
$('answer_73'): null
....

### updated

sorry for all, finally i found what't gone wrong.. it's simply a type:

```
<div class="answer" id="answer_<%= answer.id %> "
```

it's the trailing whitespace which cause this 'strange' behaviour. maybe the prototype lib strips the trailig id when returning an object's id so the error didn't occur in the first case.

Comment: seems like your 'answer_73' element just doesn't exist.

Comment: @Luca Matteis: the element doest exist, check out the log.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry.  I think you're using an incorrect selector, though I'm not a big fan of prototype, so I don't really know.  however, jquery uses # for id, so try `$( '#answer_73' )`.  however, your example should work with mootools (thought this isn't much help, hahaha).

Comment: @Dan Beam, I think your comment is the solution. Why not make an answer from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll bet you a beer that you have two elements with the id `answer_73` in your document.

Comment: that doesn't mean you still don't have equal IDs. Since the first `answer.id` will just output the ID depending on the iteration, while the second `$('answer_73')` will look in the entire document for that id, and if found more than one will give you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me (Firefox 3.5, latest prototype.js):

```
<html><head><title></title>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script>
function _debug (msg) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>"+msg+"</p>";
}
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $$('.answer').each(function(answer) {
    _debug("inside each, .id: "+answer.id);  // works
    _debug("inside each, byId .id: "+document.getElementById(answer.id));
  });
  _debug("outside each, byId literal: "+document.getElementById('answer_73'));
});

</script>
</head><body>

<div id="answer_72" class="answer"></div>
<div id="answer_73" class="answer">foo</div>
<div id="answer_74" class="answer"></div>

</body></html>
```

results in

> foo
>
> inside each, .id: answer_72
>
> inside each, byId .id: [object
>   HTMLDivElement]
>
> inside each, .id: answer_73
>
> inside each, byId .id: [object
>   HTMLDivElement]
>
> inside each, .id: answer_74
>
> inside each, byId .id: [object
>   HTMLDivElement]
>
> outside each, byId literal: [object
>   HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 1):

You're in documents's scope there. I'd also suggest you to use Firebug's `console.log()` function instead of `alert()` for debugging, then edit your topic.

Comment: I deleted my comment before you posted your response. It was sarcastic, not an actual stack overflow rule. I just thought it a little rude to ask someone to edit their topic to use your preferred logging method.

Comment: It was just a friendly recommendation, not making someone use what I want him to.